# DOM tree traversal with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

I need a jQuery selector to target `FooClass` and `BarClass` via  `#MainSelector`

```
<div id='MainSelector1'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Toto</legend>
            <div class='section'>
                <label>Koko</label>
            <div>
                <input type='text' id='KokoId'>
            </div>
            </div>   
            <div class='section'>
                <label>Foo</label>
                <div>
                    <select class='FooClass' /> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='section'>
                <label>Bar</label>
                <div>
                    <select class='BarClass' />
                </div>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>   

<div id='MainSelector2'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Toto</legend>
            <div class='section'>
                <label>Koko</label>
            <div>
                <input type='text' id='KokoId'>
            </div>
            </div>   
            <div class='section'>
                <label>Foo</label>
                <div>
                    <select class='FooClass' /> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='section'>
                <label>Bar</label>
                <div>
                    <select class='BarClass' />
                </div>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Should be something like

```
$("#MainSelector1.FooClass").Css('display', none);
$("#MainSelector1.BarClass").Css('display', none);

$("#MainSelector2.FooClass").Css('display', none);
$("#MainSelector2.BarClass").Css('display', none);
```

Comment: You can also use `.hide()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just separate the accessors with a space to also access its non-direct children and pass `none` as a string to the `css` function.

```
$("#MainSelector1 .FooClass").css('display', 'none');
$("#MainSelector1 .BarClass").css('display', 'none');

$("#MainSelector2 .FooClass").css('display', 'none');
$("#MainSelector2 .BarClass").css('display', 'none');
```

You could also do *this and that*, but maybe you should just do some reading of the [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and probably the [hide function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var $el = $('#MainSelector1');
$el.find( '.FooClass' ).css('display', 'none');
$el.find( '.BarClass' ).css('display', 'none');

$el = $('#MainSelector2');
$el.find( '.FooClass' ).css('display', 'none');
$el.find( '.BarClass' ).css('display', 'none');
```

OR

```
$('#MainSelector1').find( '.FooClass, .BarClass' ).css('display', 'none');
$('#MainSelector2').find( '.FooClass, .BarClass' ).css('display', 'none');
```

OR Simply

```
$('#MainSelector1').find( '.FooClass, .BarClass' ).hide();
$('#MainSelector2').find( '.FooClass, .BarClass' ).hide();
```